# repeatedly selects and removes a random entry from an arraylist in Java

Tags: java

> write a program that repeatedly selects and removes a random entrys
> from an arraylist. until array holds no more entries.

I hard it very hard to iterate it in here. Since every time the arraylist position is random. I also need edge case when random number is 0.
Anyway the follow is my code. So how to do it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class R3_1 {
    public ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    {cars.add("Volvo");
    cars.add("BMW");
    cars.add("Ford");
    cars.add("Mazda");}


    public String  removeentry() {

        int size = cars.size();
        Random rn = new Random();
        int a  = rn.nextInt(size) ;


        System.out.println(cars.get(a));
        cars.remove(a);

        a = a-1;
        System.out.println(cars.get(a));
        cars.remove(a);
        
        a = a-1;
        System.out.println(cars.get(a));
        cars.remove(a);

        System.out.println(cars.get(a));
        cars.remove(a);
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop.

Comment: iterate `length` times using a `for` or `while` the array list is not empty. Within the loop body pick a random number between 0 and the current length of the array. Remove the specified index. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a `while` loop, and you ask each time for new random value, given the new list size

```
public String removeentry() {
    Random rn = new Random();
    int a;
    String removed;
    while (!cars.isEmpty()) {
        a = rn.nextInt(cars.size());
        removed = cars.remove(a);
        System.out.println(removed);
    }
    return "done";
}
```

Also possible with a `for` loop

```
public String removeentry() {
    Random rn = new Random();
    int a;
    String removed;
    for (int i = cars.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        a = rn.nextInt(i);
        removed = cars.remove(a);
        System.out.println(removed);
    }
    return "done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public String removeEntries() {
  Random random = new Random();
  int size, a;
  // Execute until list is empty (and thus `cars.size() == 0`)
  while ((size = cars.size()) > 0) {
      // Select random index
      a = random.nextInt(size);
      // Output object
      System.out.println(cars.get(a));
      // Remove object from list
      cars.remove(a);
  }
  return "done";
}
```